# data validation list if cel in table contains

Tags: excel, validation, dropdown

I have created an excel file to keep record of worked hours and revenue for each customer and each employee, also i created a sheet with projects for each customer that also keeps record of the total worked hours per project etc.

- I create a project and choose the customer (Sheet 2)
- I go back to my hour registration sheet and set the starting time and choose the customer from a dropdown menu (Sheet 1; A2) (data validation)
- Then i would like to filter the second cel (Sheet 1; B2) with a dropdown menu containing the projects so it only shows projects for that specific customer.
- When i finish a project i mark the project as finished by choosing "Yes" in the last cel of the row. (Sheet 2)
- Then i would like the project dropdown menu to also filter the finished projects. (IF="Yes" dont show on data validation)

I've tried all kinds but nothing works with my current setup.
Any suggestions?

Comment: mind sharing some sample data, expected output / screenshot ?

Comment: i added an new post to make my question more clear:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53636751/excel-data-validation-list-row-a-if-cels-in-rows-in-b-are-empty

Comment: you may delete this question if the new post is sufficient. ( :

Answer (score 0):

Are you using some kind of VBA or doing it through Formulas? if you are using vba then show the code here.