# Excel Data Validation : List row A IF cells in rows in B are empty

Tags: excel, list, excel-formula

I am trying to create a data validation list that only shows the cells in the row if the cell next to it is empty. Below you can find an enclosed image with the result I would like to achieve.

So something like data validation list: row A IF cells in rows in B are empty

[image: Excel Data Validation Task]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Your question definitely needs attention ! It's a good one.

Comment: If you use a helper (additional column to get list of empty cells values from column A) column then it would be easier to get those.

Answer (score 0):

In `C2` put `=IF(B2="no","",A2)` and drag it to `C5`.

Then select the cell C2:C5 for the select from list option for the data validation.

Hope it helps..

[Edit to cater for clean..]

do :

```
D1  --->  =COUNTA(D2:D5)-COUNTBLANK(D2:D5)          
D2  --->  =IF(B2="no","",A2)
E2  --->  =IF(D2="",E1,E1+1)
F2  --->  =F1+1
G2  --->  =IFERROR(INDEX(D:D,MATCH(F2,E:E,0)),"")
```

and drag `D2:G2` to `G5` .

in the validation source.. put in :

```
=IF(D1=1,$G$2,IF(D1=2,$G$2:$G$3,IF(D1=3,$G$2:$G$4,IF(D1=4,$G$2:$G$5))))
```

I think that will do the clean up.

Comment: Hi Phidot, 
This would result in the following:

[Screenshot][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYo6B.png

As you can see the empty cells in the dropdown list are included. Also i get an extra row on my sheet. I would like to keep the sheet "clean and neat", is there any way to put a formula inside the datavalidation?

Thanks in advance.